# How is a "constant" defined with consideration to common Python coding style?

Tags: python, coding-style, google-style-guide

Constants are usually evident from ALL_CAPS names, and near the top of modules, however, it is not clear to me how one defines a constant. Is a constant:

- **A)** A reference to a value which is not intended to be changed throughout the life of the software (e.g. `PI=3.1416`)
- **B)** A  reference to a value which is expected to be changed throughout the life of the software (e.g. `CUSTOMER_FILE=r'\data\customer_info.csv'` )
- **C)** Both?

Comment: Python doesn't have a concept of a constant, this is merely an (in)formal convention. Constants as such are expected to be, well, constant, and not change. As such, I find your question confusing and unclear.

Comment: ... and probably homework.